# Scan site for used fonts, weights, styles

Tags: php, fonts

We've been doing a lot of PageSpeed optimization projects lately and found a big issue with sites loading tons of fonts, many of which often aren't even used anywhere.  I'm trying to find a good tool for automating the research into what fonts/weights/styles are even used.  I see some cool tools like Fonts Ninja, which will list the fonts used on a page, but we still have to load up a bunch of pages and manually record all that info.

Does anyone know of any tools that will crawl an entire site and create a spreadsheet or such of all the used fonts/styles?  We could try building something in PHP if not, maybe with domdocument, any ideas on that?

Thanks for any help/leads in advance!

Philip

Comment: To the best of my understanding this is not really necessarily, since modern browsers have for several years only loaded fonts and weights that are actually used on the page. Happy to be proven wrong, but this is the situation as I understand things.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we have to do some JavaScript for this. For anyone else, we're using the below, which we'll submit via AJAX for our PHP system.

```
if ( typeof getComputedStyle == "undefined" ) {
    getComputedStyle = function( elem ) { return elem.currentStyle; }
}

var who, nodes = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'), font_styles = {};
for ( var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++ ) {    
    who = nodes[i];
    if ( who.style ) {
        fontFamily = getComputedStyle(who, '')['fontFamily'];
        fontWeight = getComputedStyle(who, '')['fontWeight'];
        fontStyle = getComputedStyle(who, '')['fontStyle'];
        key = fontFamily + fontWeight + fontStyle;
        font_styles[key] = { fontFamily, fontWeight, fontStyle }
    }
}
console.log( font_styles );
```